# How to use adobe photoshop to recognize font-family in a png image

Tags: image, fonts, image-recognition

I have a png image with text I cant identify, is there any way maybe though adobe photoshop or any other means to recognize font-family on an image.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't do this. It's an image editor, not a font detector. Everyone *already* claims this software is bloated. (Also, how is this programming-related?)

Answer (score 6):

Photoshop now has a built-in font recognition feature as of CC 2015.5 called [Match Font](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/fonts.html#match_fonts).

Simply go to the `Type` menu and select `Match Font` and then crop the area to the font you'd like to try to recognize.

Additionally here are other resources to help you identify a font. (I pulled this list from a [Graphic Design Stack Exchange Meta Post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366))

- [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
- [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)
- [Serif Font Identification Guide](http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php)
- [What Font is](http://whatfontis.com/)
- [Fontspring Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator)

Comment: I was just about to bring this up, thanks for including all the useful references as well! :)

Answer (score 5):

there are a few web sites that can find the font face for you, like http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 1):

There is a free Photoshop plugin [Font Detector](http://www.layerhero.com/photoshop-font-detector/) that uses [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) service to recognize fonts on an image inside a selection.